# Programmatic way of calculating end of week/month/year

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I'm trying to build functions that help me execute frequent sparse tree queries, using `org-match-sparse-tree nil "<some_query>"` in my code.

Some of these queries need to contain constraints such as `SCHEDULED<=<end_of_this_month>`, where `<end_of_this_month>` just means the end of the current month. The same could be true for this week, next week, this year, and so on.

I know about the possibility of writing `SCHEDULED<=<1+y>`, but that just means 1 year from now, meaning, as of the time of this writing, from Aug 28 2019 to Aug 27 2020, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to, programmatically, obtain in a string the end of the current or next month/year/week without having to manually calculate those (meaning using a preexisting date-handling function)?

Comment: The `calendar.el` library has a function:  `(calendar-last-day-of-month MONTH YEAR)`.  There is *probably* a buit-in function to obtain the current month / year, but if not, you can extract it form `(current-time)` and/or `format-time-string` that defaults to the current time .....  See also `org-time-today`, `parse-time-string` and `org-parse-time-string` ...

Comment: See also the `elmo.el` library that has a function that is easily extracted/separated called `elmo-time-to-datevec` (which relies on the built-in `timezone.el` library) -- see https://github.com/wanderlust/wanderlust/blob/master/elmo/elmo-date.el  E.g., `(elmo-time-to-datevec (current-time))` at this precise moment in time returns `[2019 8 28 14 50 56 (-25200 "PDT")]` and we can then extract the `nth` element from the vector ...

Comment: `(calendar-last-day-of-month (string-to-number (format-time-string "%m")) (string-to-number (format-time-string "%y")))`

Comment: I think that would work. Hmm, I wonder how to get the last day of the current week, now?

Comment: Here is a link that contains a function `last-day-of-week` ... https://www.andersen.berlin/emacs.d/  I have not studied to see who wrote it ....  The result is in time and needs to be converted ...

Comment: The last one is actually a really good answer and if you want to turn it into an actual answer I can accept it. In that code the author converts the time to a string as well, which is perfect.

Comment: Inasmuch as I do not presently have time to test the code and properly research who and/or what libraries should receive credit for the code that I found out there on the net, it would be appreciated if you could write up a solution that will be helpful to future Google searchers who will visit this thread ....  I'm currently swamped with work and was just hoping to post comments here and there on my coffee break.  :)

Comment: No worries. Same here, I totally get it. Just wanted to give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur Andersen has published his emacs configuration, and contains exactly these functions, [here](https://www.andersen.berlin/emacs.d/). (Credit to @lawlist for pointing out where this was, in the comments to the original question.)

The functions to calculate end of the day/month/year are:

```
(defun last-day-of-year ()
  "Return the last day of the year as time."
  (encode-time 0 0 0 31 12 (nth 5 (decode-time
                                    (current-time)))))

(defun last-day-of-month ()
  "Return the last day of month as time."
  (let* ((now (decode-time (current-time)))
         (month (nth 4 now))
         (year (nth 5 now))
         (last-day-of-month (calendar-last-day-of-month month year)))
        (encode-time 0 0 0 last-day-of-month month year)))

(defun last-day-of-week ()
  "Return the last day of the week as time."
  (let* ((now (current-time))
         (datetime (decode-time now))
         (dow (nth 6 datetime)))
        (time-add now (days-to-time (- 7 dow)))))
```

These functions return a time, not a date, so you need to convert them appropriately, such as:

```
(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d" (last-day-of-year))
```